# Create view from 3 different tables?

Tags: mysql, join, create-view

I'm trying to create a view in MySQL to include from 3 different tables.

```
CREATE TABLE ACTOR (
    ACTOR_ID    DECIMAL (2,0) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    ACTOR_FIRST CHAR(25), 
    ACTOR_LAST  CHAR(30), 
    DOB         DATE
);

CREATE TABLE DIRECTOR (
    DIRECTOR_ID     DECIMAL(2,0) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    DIRECTOR_FIRST  CHAR(25), 
    DIRECTOR_LAST   CHAR(30) 
);

CREATE TABLE FILM (
    FILM_ID         DECIMAL(2,0) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    TITLE           CHAR(50), 
    RELEASE_DATE    DATE, 
    DIRECTOR_ID     DECIMAL(2,0), 
    GENRE_ID        CHAR(10), 
    PRODUCTION_ID   CHAR(3) 
);
```

The `VIEW` I'm trying to create:

```
create view film_production as 
select 
    title, 
    actor_first, 
    actor_last, 
    director_first, 
    director_last, 
    Production_id, 
    release_date 
from    film, 
        actor, 
        director
;
```

This gives me like 192 results. But I only have 3 actors, with 8 movies with 8 directors, and 6 production_id's. Another thing to note is 1 movie has 2 of the 3 actors in it, so I should have at least 9 movies that show not 192. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I just cant figure this out. I'm thinking maybe a `join` or some kind.

Comment: Where are the tables you can join on?  e.g. A table that has the Actor <-> Film and Director <-> Film relationship?  Without those you are doing a full outer join and getting the product of all tables (# actors * # directors * # films)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought of adding referential keys between actor and film, and director and film tables?

**Actor**

```
CREATE TABLE ACTOR (
    ID        INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(25), 
    LASTNAME  VARCHAR(30), 
    DOB       DATE
);
```

**Director**

```
CREATE TABLE DIRECTOR (
    ID         INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    FIRSTNAME  VARCHAR(25), 
    LASTNAME   VARCHAR(30) 
);
```

**Film with connections to actor and director**

```
CREATE TABLE FILM (
    FILM_ID         INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    TITLE           VARCHAR(50), 
    RELEASE_DATE    DATE, 
    DIRECTOR_ID     INT, 
    GENRE_ID        INT, 
    PRODUCTION_ID   INT,
    ACTOR_ID        INT,
    CONSTRAINT FK_FILM_DIRECTOR_ID FOREIGN KEY (DIRECTOR_ID)
    REFERENCES DIRECTOR(ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_FILM_ACTOR_ID FOREIGN KEY (ACTOR_ID)
    REFERENCES ACTOR(ID)
);
```

**View combining the 3 tables**

```
create view film_production as 
select 
    title, 
    a.firstname as actor_firstname, 
    a.lastname as actor_lastname, 
    d.firstname as director_firstname, 
    d.lastname as directory_lastname, 
    Production_id, 
    release_date 
from       film f
left join actor a on f.actor_id = a.id
left join director d on f.director_id = d.id;
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9fe1e

Note that I have used INT instead of DECIMAL for ID fields and VARCHAR instead of CHAR fields. This may help in allocating the right space for most general purpose uses.

Comment: Oh nice i used yours and i had to make changes to the INT fields for P.ID and G.ID since those two fields actually use letters and some special characters and I put the rest of the tables into my database as a test. it works. just one problem is that with your setup and the changes i made to it. It does not show the 2nd movie that the other actor also plays in. But so far that works so im going to modify my database and modify your setup to fit my needs.

Comment: how do i turn this into answered?

Comment: I don't think this is the correct answer to the problem as there are more than one actor per movie. With this schema you would have to have multiple FILM entries to account for multiple actors in the move

Comment: yes that is true, but as i stated before i have only 3 actors in this Database and with that view that im trying to create. I want to show all the movies that each 3 of those actors who act in them along with the other information.

Comment: So in the end i will want this view to have all the movies that i put in the database that only belong to one of the three actors for example. robert downy Jr. i will have all his movies in my database and actor johnny depp i will also have all his movies in my database. so when i create this view i want it to show all both of those actors movies. so the multiple entries are actually coming from the actors names but with a different movie on each row.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your view should use joins.

BUT, it looks like you are missing a table, something like film_actor.
Using the missing table, and assuming you are trying to get the cast and directors of each movie it would be

```
SELECT 
  FILM.*
 ,ACTOR_FIRST + ' ' + ACTOR_LAST AS actor
 ,DIRECTOR_FIRST + ' ' + DIRECTOR_LAST AS director
FROM FILM
INNER JOIN FILM_ACTOR fa ON fa.FILM_ID = FILM.FILM_ID
INNER JOIN ACTOR ON ACTOR.ACTOR_ID = FILM_ACTOR.ACTOR_ID
INNER JOIN DIRECTOR d ON d.DIRECTOR_ID = FILM.DIRECTOR_ID
```

Like I mentioned, you are missing a table that would hold *multiple actors* and associate them to one movie: a one to many relationship.

Comment: Well the only other table that would be useful would be my actor_movies table which has only the FILM_ID, ACTOR_ID, TITLE. Maybe I should make that table to include, the actor names instead of actor_id.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was talking about :) .

Comment: That table should REALLY be called ACTOR_FILM though for clarity ( to show that it relates your other two tables )

Comment: So I would instead use 4 tables with the inner joins, but change my actor_movies table to include the names of the actors correct?

Comment: Yes, and then no. You need to use the four tables. The actor_movies table should hold actor_id and movie_id and that is all. By joining onto that in your view, you will get all the actors for the movie.